# howto encrypt passwords to the database using the Secured - Security.Authenticato

Tags: playframework, salt, password-encryption

Im trying to save my passwords with some kind of security into the database.
What is the best way of doing this with the play framework?
Do I encrypt the string in javascript? Wouldnt have thought this was the best way?
or send normal string and then encrypt when saving to database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't matter if you use Play or any other system - encrypting passwords on client side make no sense as it can be re-engineered easily so you can just also store them as plain text (of course it's bad idea)

Instead you should use *at least* some well known techniques for storing passwords like [salted encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) - it can be achieved with [jBCrypt](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/) and of course it need to be done at the server side.

Comment: Thanks I used this and it was very easy to set up.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [security guide](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/security)?
It is pretty complete and well explained.

Comment: The problem is that the Crpto library has changed from version 1.2 to 2 and has removed some methods like encryptAES and decryptAES.